# Replacing table name with a variable in a query

Tags: c++, string, qt

i have the following code.My table is called 'tableu'.I want replace  'tableu' with a variable that will hold the table name. How can i represent that.

```
   query.prepare(
                "INSERT INTO tableu (village, weight, diet, age)"
                "VALUES (:village, :weight, :diet, :age)"
                );
```

Comment: That is not supported by prepared statements. You have to solve it in C++ with string manipulation, for example `QString.arg()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change your table name from `tableu` to lets say `NewTableName`, it can be done using any of the following syntax:

```
query.prepare(
              "RENAME tableu TO NewTableName"
             );
```

OR

```
query.prepare(
              "ALTER TABLE tableu RENAME TO NewTableName"
             );
```

Update:

May be the OP is looking for this.

```
QString tableName = QString("tableu");
QString sqlQuery = QString("INSERT INTO %1 (village, weight, diet, age) VALUES (:village, :weight, :diet, :age)").arg(tableName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but this code will let you have a variable that may contain different tables names placed in the query

```
  char sBuffer [1024];

  char sQueryTable[] = "tableu";

  sprintf(sBuffer , "INSERT INTO %s (village, weight, diet, age) VALUES (:village, :weight, :diet, :age)", sQueryTable);

  query.prepare(sBuffer);
```

Read about sprinft and formatting strings [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Note: you can always use std::strings as well and concatenate the string together from a variable holding your table name and the rest of the string